# Importing CSV to DataGridView Error With CheckBox Column

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview, export-to-csv

I have a DataGridView where I save the values to a CSV file. The code creates an empty value in the CSV where there is an empty cell in the DataGridView. The problem I have is with Column 10 in the DataGridView. This is a CheckBox column. The value of this column is “Nothing” unless it has been either checked or unchecked in which case the value becomes 0 or 1 (False or True).

When I load the CSV back into the DataGridView, if there is an empty value for the CheckBox Column I get an error. The DataGridView does not accept a “Nothing” value for this Column when importing from a CSV.

Is there a way to export the value of Column 10 only as 0 or 1?

Hoping someone can help me resolve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

This is the code I use to Save the DataGridView to a CSV file.

```
        Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                   Where Not row.IsNewRow
                   Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
        Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(Path)
            For Each r In rows
                sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
            Next
        End Using
```

And this is the code I use to load the CSV back into the DataGridView.

```
        Try
            Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(FullPath)
            'Read CSV file content 
            While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
                rowvalue = streamReader.ReadLine()
                cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c)
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(cellvalue)
            End While
            streamReader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("File not found")
        End Try
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Do you want the grid to only contain `True` and `False`? Do you want the grid to contain `Nothing` but export that as `False`? Do you want the file to contain empty values but import them as `False`? Do you wan the file to contain empty values and import them as `Nothing`? All those pare possibilities.

Comment: I would suggest that the specific issue is that you are importing that data as empty `Strings` rather than as `Nothing`. You need to decide what problem you're actually trying to fix. Do you want to import the data you have properly or have different data to import?

Comment: I just tested and I can confirm that importing `Nothing` into a check box column works perfectly well but importing an empty `String` doesn't. This is exactly what you should expect, given that the column contained `Nothing` in the first place but a `String` of any kind in a column that expects `True` or `False` makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reponse @jmcilhinney. I have the underlying values of the checkbox column set to 0 and 1. Ideally there wouldn’t be any “nothing” value for the checkbox column, only 0 or 1, so when I export to CSV and reimport it, there shouldn’t be any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any empty values in that column then don't allow any. The simplest option for that is to set `Value` of the cell in that column to `False` when a row is added, if it's not already set to something else:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_RowsAdded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowsAdded
    Dim cell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(checkBoxColumnIndex)
    Dim value = cell.Value

    If value Is Nothing Then
        cell.Value = False
    End If
End Sub
```

With that, `False` effectively becomes the default value for that column. All your existing export and import code will just work.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand you need something like this. This is your code with some changes that helps you understand how to achieve your goal.
Obviously there are other approaches where one of those is this:
(Note that it's not tested it's only dimonstrative, you have to work/test it)

```
    Dim indexOfCheckBoxColumn As Integer = 10
    Dim getValues As Func(Of DataGridViewCell, String) = Function(c As DataGridViewCell)
                                                             If c.ColumnIndex = indexOfCheckBoxColumn Then
                                                                 If c.Value Is Nothing Then Return "0"
                                                                 Return CStr(IIf(Convert.ToBoolean(DirectCast(c, DataGridViewCheckBoxCell).Value) = True, "1", "0"))
                                                             Else

                                                                 If c.Value IsNot Nothing Then Return c.Value.ToString
                                                             End If
                                                             Return ""
                                                         End Function


    Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
               Where Not row.IsNewRow
               Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(cell) getValues(cell))


    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter(Path)
        For Each r In rows
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
        Next
    End Using
```